# php: print variables in for loop

Tags: php

I hvae three variables,

```
$title_1 $title_2 $title_3
```

how can i print them in for loop?

what i've tried:

```
$number = 3;
    for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++){
            echo "$title_($i+1)";
    }
```

Comment: Try `echo ${"title_" . $i};`

Comment: Use an array. Anyone who suggests anything else is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't meddle with these things; use an array for this stuff.

```
$titles = array('first title', 'second title', 'third title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo $title;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work, haven't tested

```
for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++){
        echo ${"title_$i"};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $var = "title_".$i;
    echo $$var;
}
```

But I wouldn't. This is really, REALLY bad design. Use arrays.